# How to handle CMake ExternalProject when repo (googletest) has multiple libraries?

Tags: github, cmake, googletest

How can I add external projects in CMake when the project's repo isn't the root of the library I want to use, but in fact contains two directories which are each root directories of repos that I want to use in my project?

I'm working to set up a framework CMake project that uses Google Test and Mock for testing, however when I try to download the google test repo (https://github.com/google/googletest) with `ExternalProject_Add`, it complains on build that it can't find the source for the project. Well, that's because Google have merged googletest and googlemock into a single project, except it's now two projects.

Some of the repo's file structure:

```
googletest-master/
├──[...no CMakeFiles.txt exists here...]
├──googletest/
│  ├──src/
│  └──CMakeFiles.txt
└──googlemock/
   ├──src/
   └──CMakeFiles.txt
```

When I do the following...

```
ExternalProject_Add(
    gtest
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/google/googletest.git
    TIMEOUT 10
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
    LOG_DOWNLOAD ON
    LOG_CONFIGURE ON
    LOG_BUILD ON
    PREFIX "googletest-master"
)
```

...it downloads the actual repo to `googletest-master/src/gtest` because I'm prefixing the repo with "googletest-master" to keep it out of my main source code, and it assumes that I'm downloading a project that is only source and that source is in the root directory.

So I'd like to accomplish two things:

1. Download the repo into the googletest-master directory, exactly as it would be if I cloned the repo there, or downloaded the zip off GitHub and extracted it.
2. Build and include both googletest and googlemock in my CMake project

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need *single* download step, but *two* build steps. Different `ExternalProject_add` command calls cannot *share* steps, but you can arrange all these steps into different calls with appropriate dependencies between them:

```
# Single download(git clone)
ExternalProject_Add(
    googletest-master
    DOWNLOAD_DIR "googletest-master/src" # The only dir option which is required
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/google/googletest.git
    TIMEOUT 10
    LOG_DOWNLOAD ON
    # Disable all other steps
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
    BUILD_COMMAND ""
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
)

# Build gtest from existing sources
ExternalProject_Add(
    gtest
    DOWNLOAD_COMMAND "" # No download required
    SOURCE_DIR "googletest-master/src/googletest" # Use specific source dir
    PREFIX "googletest-master" # But use prefix for compute other dirs
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
    LOG_CONFIGURE ON
    LOG_BUILD ON
)

# gtest should be build after being downloaded
add_dependencies(gtest googletest-master)

# Build gmock from existing sources
ExternalProject_Add(
    gmock
    DOWNLOAD_COMMAND "" # No download required
    SOURCE_DIR "googletest-master/src/googlemock" # Use specific source dir
    PREFIX "googletest-master" # But use prefix for compute other dirs
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
    LOG_CONFIGURE ON
    LOG_BUILD ON
)

# gmock should be build after being downloaded
add_dependencies(gmock googletest-master)
```

Comment: I ended up doing some customization of some of the relative paths to suit my needs/preferences a bit more -- this solution raw led to some needlessly complex-seeming directory structures (googletest-master/src/googletest/src). But this works and is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I have a [repository](https://github.com/apbarrero/cpp-utest) where I import gtest and gmock libraries using CMake, just as you want to, but using the old SVN source repository instead of GIT.

I think the key is getting sources only for gmock, since it includes gtest sources and then export both libraries.

The [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/apbarrero/cpp-utest/blob/master/test/CMakeLists.txt) looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

include(ExternalProject)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(GMOCK_VERSION "1.7.0")
set(GMOCK_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/gmock-${GMOCK_VERSION}")
ExternalProject_Add(project_gmock
    SVN_REPOSITORY http://googlemock.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release-${GMOCK_VERSION}
    PREFIX ${GMOCK_DIR}
    CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:PATH=${CMAKE_C_COMPILER} -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:PATH=${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}
    # Disable update step
    UPDATE_COMMAND ""
    # Disable install step
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
)
ExternalProject_Get_Property(project_gmock source_dir)
ExternalProject_Get_Property(project_gmock binary_dir)

include_directories(${source_dir}/gtest/include)
add_library(gtest STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET gtest PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${binary_dir}/gtest/libgtest.a)
add_dependencies(gtest project_gmock)
add_library(gtest_main STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET gtest_main PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${binary_dir}/gtest/libgtest_main.a)
add_dependencies(gtest_main project_gmock)
include_directories(${source_dir}/include)
add_library(gmock STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET gmock PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${binary_dir}/libgmock.a)
add_dependencies(gmock project_gmock)
add_library(gmock_main STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET gmock_main PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${binary_dir}/libgmock_main.a)
add_dependencies(gmock_main project_gmock)

include_directories(${cpp_utest_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++")
#add_executable(utests )
#target_link_libraries(utests gmock_main gmock gtest pthread)
```